# Qt C++ - Connect multiple objects to one signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am trying to connect two `QSpinBox` into the range (max/min value) of a `QSlider`

```
connect(
  ui->lowerFrameBox,
  SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
  ui->timeSlider,
  SLOT(setRange(int,int)));
```

Is what I'm using at the moment, but of course it will not work because that only returns a single int. I need to either connect both into this, which I doubt you can, or set the later int to it's current value, which in this context is confusing me. Any help appreciated, new to Qt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read documentation carefully.

`QSlider` has public functions `void setMaximum ( int )` and `void setMinimum ( int )`. Probably that is what you are looking for.

Good luck!